# Running Expect script on windows

Tags: tcl, expect

I've the expect script running on linux which I want to run it on windows. I've added

```
 #!/bin/sh
 # \
 exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

 package require Expect
```

lines as well at the start. I'm getting '`can't find package Expect`' error. where can I get that?

Comment: Check out the expect open source page: http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Expect for Windows? Check out ActiveState…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Expect for Windows](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.6/expect4win/welcome.html) is done by ActiveState as part of [ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl) (no charge for the 32-bit version), which is highly recommended as *the* definitive batteries-included build of Tcl on the Windows platform. (I'm not sure if Expect for Windows is part of the Community Edition; I'm on a different platform so checking is a little awkward.)

---

Be aware that there are some substantial differences between Unix and Windows under the covers, and Expect is an extension package that gets *very* deep into the details. It hides nearly all the horrible differences, but not all; advanced scripts may need quite a bit of extra work to port. Also, some Windows executables (notably `telnet.exe`) can't be wrapped by Expect because they're marked as special system files, and GUI apps can't be wrapped at all. There are often good alternatives for subordinate processes though.